# Firebase Sorting Data Retrieval

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code that I have: I am trying to get data stored in the Firebase Database sorted by wage. The order of the database goes: "Posts -> PostID(.push when saving) -> Wage."  I have the data retrieval working just not in order. 
[image]

```
var PostsRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Posts");
PostsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  var title = data.val().title;
  var description = data.val().description;
  var completionDate = data.val().completionDate;
  var complexity = data.val().complexity;
  var wage = data.val().wage;
  var uid = data.val().userID;
});
```

Comment: How are you storing the posts? Are you storing each post in an array of posts?

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the wages as string, which means that they will be sorted in lexicographical order:

> 1
>
> 13
>
> 2
>
> 20
>
> 3

If you want to get the results in numerical order, you should store the wages as numbers, so without the quotes.

If you store them from your code, this might require that you convert it with `parseInt(wagesAsString)`.

After you store the wages as numbers, you can get them in order with:

```
var PostsRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Posts");
var query = PostsRef.orderByChild("wage");
query.on('child_added', function(data) {
```

Comment: Ahh. So after I save the wage as a number where in the code should I include the code: ".orderByChild()"? Should it be at the end of the PostsRef declaration?

Comment: I added a sample of this.