# Firebase and Android: Order Query Results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a short Question about my Code.

I'm using a recyclerview in my Android App, and fill it with some data out of my Firebase Database.

It works well, but I notice that the ordering is not right :/

I have this Code:

```
private void getRankings() {
        // hole anzahl an Teilnehmern
        mDatabase.child(TEILNEHMERDATA).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // hole Anzahl aller Teilnehmer um das Ranking zu bestimmen
                teilnehmerVar = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                mDatabase.child(TEILNEHMERDATA).orderByChild("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    Teilnehmer teilnehmer = new Teilnehmer();
                    int i = teilnehmerVar+1;
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        // teamname, Platzierung, Punkte
                        int punkteStand = (int) Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue()));

                        i -= 1;
                        this.teilnehmer = new Teilnehmer(dataSnapshot.getKey(), ((String) dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue()), "Platz " + i, punkteStand + " Punkte");
                        teilnehmerList.add(0, this.teilnehmer);     // add to recyclerview: add(0, teilnehmer) gebe in desc aus von 0 zum n. eintrag
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    // save
                    }
```

In this row:

```
mDatabase.child(TEILNEHMERDATA).orderByChild("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
```

Order Child by score

I get my Data with Structure like this:

```
"Teilnehmer" : {
    "user_0gPpHXzKqLd2xA" : {
      "image" : "",
      "score" : "0",
      "startnummer" : "1",
      "teamname" : "Andy Foo"
    },
```

The row score contains an Integer with a Datarange from 0 to ∞

My Layout looks like:

```
Teamname1    9 Punkte
Platz 1

Teamname2    0 Punkte
Platz 2

Teamname3    1000 Punkte
Platz 3
```

But its absolutely wrong :/

9 is bigger than 10000
seems my Query order only by the first number

1..2..3..

My Recyclerview initialization:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried to use `orderByValue()` method?

Comment: This was a fast reply. Yeah tried with orderByValue().startAt("0").endAt("99999999")  but does not work (i do not get anything data)

Comment: Have you tried to use in stead of this line: `mDatabase.child(TEILNEHMERDATA).orderByChild("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {` this line of code: `mDatabase.child(TEILNEHMERDATA).child(userId).orderByChild("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {`? In which `userId` is the id that see right beneath the `TEILNEHMERDATA` node.

Comment: Thanks, it works with integer or double numbers. But i must use an backend (for other people) to manage these data, and these backend store all data elements as a String... can i use the rules validation to cast these string into integer or double value? this could solve my problem as well. I can not change the backend (Web Gui from 3rd party developer) to store these element directly as int / double

Comment: @AlexMamo TEILNEHMERDATA contains only the Tablename: private String TEILNEHMERDATA = "Teilnehmer"; 

userID is the firebase authenticaton UID + my prefix user_$UID i will try it with .child(user_$iuid)

Comment: In this case i see that you are missing a child, `user_0gPpHXzKqLd2xA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store values as strings, they will be order lexicographically. To get the wanted order, either store them as numbers or store them in a string that also orders the way you want. E.g.

```
"Teilnehmer" : {
    "user_0gPpHXzKqLd2xA" : {
      "image" : "",
      "score" : "00000",
      "startnummer" : "1",
      "teamname" : "Andy Foo"
    },
    "user_0gPpHXzKqLd2xB" : {
      "image" : "",
      "score" : "00123",
      "startnummer" : "1",
      "teamname" : "Andy Bar"
    },
```

So in the above structure when you order on `score` it will still end up sorted according to the numeric value too. This a common trick, for example you will often see dates formatted as `2017-06-19` since that ensures they order in the correct way for dates (even though the type is a string).

Note that I only recommend doing this because of your back-end system limitation. In most cases, you should simply store numbers as numbers and prevent this workaround.

See:

- [Firebase query ordering not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174300/firebase-query-ordering-not-working-properly)
- [Firebase Sorting Data Retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911426/firebase-sorting-data-retrieval)
- [firebase orderByChild returns weird order for only one child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905834/firebase-orderbychild-returns-weird-order-for-only-one-child)
- [Firebase sort by points depending on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552884/firebase-sort-by-points-depending-on-date)

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to convert on server (cloud functions) from string to int?

So my backend stores data as a string, and any firebase cloud code convert it to valid integer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this when creating your recycler view

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
 layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Comment: Please let me know

Comment: So:
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());..............

can't resolve setReverseLayout :/

I have updated my first Question with better syntax / tabs

Comment: Don't use RecyclerView.LayoutManager, use LinearLayoutManager